# Stop job from running between a period of time

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I searched about that, but didn't find any resources. I have a java batch running every midnight and it takes 20minutes to finish it's execution, and I have a CI/CD pipeline using github actions, and I want to stop github actions job from running if someone tries to push a commit in this date interval: [midnight, midnight + 20min], so it will not brake the batch. Is this possible in github actions ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - actually nowadays it's much easier than before, as GitHub added native support for concurrency. It's even better than locking a  fixed time-window - it's based on workflow actual execution time.

Here are the docs:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-concurrency

Basically you just add this to top level of your workflow:

```
concurrency: 
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}
```

And it will queue up all workflows that will appear and execute them one after another.

If you would like to stop every other workflows from running not just the one, you can do:

```
concurrency: repository_lock
```

This will make all workflows queueing up - but that maybe a bit too much I think - it depends on what you need - but it's really flexbile solution.

The only alternative that was available before and it's still usable is cancelling other workflow runs if new one appears:
https://github.com/styfle/cancel-workflow-action/

But I think it's not what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I understand that this feature will allow me to lock the jobs from getting executed, but how would I tell them to not execute just between 00:00 and 00:20 time period, I want that to be automatic.

Comment: You can schedule one job that will run 20 minutes if you need that and make that blocking all others